1:Many join question for condensing the many set by a value and ordering it
Trying to write a query to join to tables 1:Many and order by the date column descending so we only get a 1:1 record, with the latest many record sorted by date.
Table 1
Id
Name
Table 2
Id
Value
Id, Name
Id, Value,Date
Id, Value,Date
Id, Value, Date <-- Want to join, and only get this record sorted by date and ignore previous records/columns
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Name, t2.value, t2.Date
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t2.Id=t1.Id
ORDER BY t2.Date DESC
GROUP BY t1.Id
Does it order, then group, giving me the latest record? Or do I need to do multiple select and union because of how order/group by work in processing?

"Does it order, then group" Why don't you try it and find out?

Also, please learn how to use GROUP BY.  Your query won't even run in most dbms.

"Does it order, then group" Why don't you try it and find out? –
Groups first, that's the problem so can't order by first but it's what I want to do in a single query (but seems I can't).  "Also, please learn how to use GROUP BY. Your query won't even run in most dbms. – " - This is correct, it needs to be group by then order by, so current tested query won't work, but it's what I want to achieve. So I can only do what I want by doing a select on one table, then a select on another table with other criteria, then join them so two queries and if that's the only way it's fine
